# Deployed Smart Contract To Remix ,Can't find launched smart contract anymore. CAN SOMEONE HELP?

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain, meta-transactions

I've launched a smart Contract using Remix.Ethereum.org after launching it I compiled the contract to code, compiler came back clean no issues (GREEN CHECK MARK). Launched Contract, Added .5 BNB to contract that was made to run on BSC NETWORK, I left the contract to run and yes I was able to interact with it and had the Action button to stop the contract but my computer ended up dying and when i turned it back on I couldn't find the contract, the compiler never errored out and there were no issues up until my comptuer turned off i thought nothing off it but after going back to repopulate picture below i was unable to find my deployed contract EVEN though i was able to launch and paired with my meta mask

CAN SOMEONE HELP ? ANYONE NEED SOME GUIDANCE

[image]

[![enter image description here

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfNXv.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfNXv.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the "Activity" section of your MetaMask. There should be an entry that reads something like "Contract Creation" which you can click on to get the address. If you want to reload it into Remix, select the matching contract (like in your first screenshot) and paste the address into the "At Address" box.

Comment: That definitely helped. I was able to reimport it I can't add pictures here i'm seeing if i can just stop the contract and receive the funds back from the contract.